# Pull Single Frame from Video Feed (DJI Mobile SDK)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, dji-sdk

I am making a DJI Mobile SDK app and have setup an application that gets live video from the drone and displays it in a view, but I need to pull a single frame from the video feed to work with and cannot figure out how to do it!

One method would be to take a picture with the drone and then download it from the SD card, but I do not require the full resolution image and it feels like there must be a simple method to just get a single frame from the video preview.

The code which casts the video stream is:

```
-(void)videoFeed:(DJIVideoFeed *)videoFeed didUpdateVideoData:(NSData *)videoData {
    [[DJIVideoPreviewer instance] push:(uint8_t *)videoData.bytes length:(int)videoData.length];
}
```

any ideas on how to pull an individual from from the feed? Or maybe is there a way to have an iOS app just take a screenshot and work with that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not very familiar with IOS. for android there is a sample which use DJI msdk to grab the still images and use the image for Panorama stitching https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-PanoramaDemo.

[image]

The equivalent IOS version of Panorama stitching is here. https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/iOS-PanoramaDemo

Maybe you can get idea on how to grab the still image from there.

Answer (score 0):

There are several threads about this in android.

Ios would not be different i think.
[how to get bitmap data from drone camera stream. android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64749724/how-to-get-bitmap-data-from-drone-camera-stream-android-application/66305873#66305873)

Get the bitmap from the fpvWidget is by far the simpliest and fastest solution.

```
public Bitmap getFrameBitmap() {
return fpvWidget.getBitmap();
}
```