# how to get bitmap data from drone camera stream. android application

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I am currently using the `videofeeder` class and `DJICodecManager` to stream the `camera view` to my application, I would like to get the `bitmap/rgba` data of this feed in order to use it as input to an `object` detection algorithm.

Comment: Do you have a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little uggly solution, but it works very well!

Display a fpvview and read the bitmap out from there. It's fast and you don't and seems to be fast enough for realtime tracking.

```
public Bitmap getFrameBitmap() {
return fpvWidget.getBitmap();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (not sure how it compares to Mat's solution performance-wise - probably worse), is based on the following demo: https://github.com/godfreynolan/DJITutorialsKotlin/tree/main/9-VideoDecoder

Which sets a YUV callback and then turns the YUV image into a bitmap.
Extracting just the critical parts:

```
class MainActivity : Activity(), DJICodecManager.YuvDataCallback {
    private var mCodecManager: DJICodecManager

    ...
    // In some initialization code
    mCodecManager?.enabledYuvData(true)
    mCodecManager?.yuvDataCallback = this

    override fun onYuvDataReceived(
        format: MediaFormat,
        yuvFrame: ByteBuffer?,
        dataSize: Int,
        width: Int,
        height: Int
    ) {
        println("YUV data received - wxh: $width x $height, size: $dataSize.  Frame: $yuvFrame")
        if ((yuvFrame != null)) {
            isProcessing = true
            val bytes = ByteArray(dataSize)
            yuvFrame[bytes]  // This actually does something!
            println("Attempting to set last cap image... count=$count")
            val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val yuvImage = createYuvImage(bytes, width, height)
            val bitmap = YuvImageToBitmap(yuvImage!!)
...



private fun createYuvImage(yuvFrame: ByteArray, width: Int, height: Int): YuvImage? {
    print("Screenshot!!")
    if (yuvFrame.size < width * height) {
        return null
    }
    println("YUV frame size: ${yuvFrame.size}")
    val length = width * height
    val u = ByteArray(width * height / 4)
    val v = ByteArray(width * height / 4)
    for (i in u.indices) {
        u[i] = yuvFrame[length + i]
        v[i] = yuvFrame[length + u.size + i]
    }
    for (i in u.indices) {
        yuvFrame[length + 2 * i] = v[i]
        yuvFrame[length + 2 * i + 1] = u[i]
    }

    val yuvImage = YuvImage(
        yuvFrame,
        ImageFormat.NV21,
        width,
        height,
        null
    )
    return yuvImage
}

fun YuvImageToBitmap(yuvImage: YuvImage): Bitmap {
    val out = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    yuvImage.compressToJpeg(Rect(0, 0, yuvImage.width, yuvImage.height), 50, out)
    val imageBytes = out.toByteArray()
    val opt = BitmapFactory.Options()
    opt.inMutable = true
    val image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.size, opt)
    return image
}
```